# No such property: ABI for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.OutputFile

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am brand new on development of React Native. I developed a small project and want to have a release APK. Bu I go stack on release build.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

The error is

> No such property: ABI for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.OutputFile
>   org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred
>   configuring project ':app' Caused by:
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ABI for class:
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.OutputFile

**build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"


project.ext.react = [
    resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ninjakod.vehiclevalue"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-admob')
    implementation project(':react-native-admob')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

**build.gradle(SampleMobileApp)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. Adding

```
import com.android.build.OutputFile
```

to the build.gradle(for app) solved the problem

Comment: Android studio was auto-deleting this line every time I tried adding, in frustration I kept pressing CMD + Z to undo changes done by Android Studio and it kept removing the line I kept adding until the build was done, and in the end, I won Android Studio Lost! this fixed the stupid issue. Thanks

Comment: I could not trick Android Studio from removing the line, by naming the class explicitly with `def abi = output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)` I could make it work

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it worked. I've used VSCode to edit the file, so Android studio was not reverting it back.

Comment: Now Android Studio tells me that com.android.build.OutputFile is deprecated.
Yet Google's own documentation still uses it: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits

Gotta "love" Google and their deprecation :(
I'll keep using this until it actually breaks as it's during build only.

Comment: I was also facing the problem with Android Studio automatically removing this line, and @Christian's solution worked for me. I only have one questions: why the hell this wasn't happening till yesterday?? ‍♂️

Answer (score 37):

replace this line in build.gradle(:app)

```
def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
```

with:

```
def abi = output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)
```